# Indexing a list of vectors in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, vector, indexing

I have a loop that is creating vectors `v_1, v_2, ... , v_n.` So far, the way I 'index' them is by creating an array `list_of_vectors=(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)` and whenever I want to call one of them, I retrieve it from this list.

Is there a smarter way to do this? In Mathematica for example, you can make an assignment `v[1]=something1`, `v[2]=something2`, and you can call it as `v[1]`, `v[2]`. I imagine this can't exactly be done in python, but is there a smarter/more efficient way of indexing my vectors than this?

Generally, all I know to do is make lists (arrays/vectors) of things, but perhaps that is silly/wasteful in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this in Python. By the way, Python does not actually have built-in "arrays"--there are lists, and `array` (a standard module) and `numpy` (a third-party but extremely common module) have their own arrays.

The first, most direct way is to use lists. If you get the vectors in the order you say, create the list with

```
v = [None]
```

Now `v[0]` is defined but you apparently will never use it. Then when you get the next vector, `v_1`, execute

```
v.append(v_1)
```

The value of `v[1]` is now the vector you just appended. The next vector will be `v[2]`, and so on.

If that is not suitable, such as the vectors coming in a more random order, you can use a dictionary. Create your dictionary with

```
v = dict()
```

or perhaps with

```
v = {}
```

Then when you get a vector, say `v_2` that you want to associate with the number `2`, execute

```
v[2] = v_2
```

Then you can later reference `v[2]` whenever you want. Note that `v[0]` and `v[1]` are not yet defined. This approach uses more memory than the list but is more flexible.

Yet another way is to define a `numpy` array of an appropriate size, then just assign to that. This also allows random order, but you must then know the largest index that you will ever use in advance. The other two ways will adjust the object size as needed.

Comment: Thanks!

I've had the issue that v.append doesn't happen in place, so while my loop is creating the vectors, they all get lost at every iteration.

The way I resolve this for now is I make a np.zero array of appropriate size and assign at every iteration the vector I want in each position, but I am afraid that might be inefficient.

Comment: @Craig: The append method does indeed happen in place. Perhaps you are doing that append to a *copy* of your desired list which then gets lost. Perhaps you should show the code where `v.append` does not seem to work properly.

Comment: Oh, I actually used the append function, which I believe is in numpy, not the append method, that should take care of it.

Comment: @Mike: You probably need to copy() the list before continuing the loop..

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do is to create using dictionaries likes this:

```
b={}
b[0]=[1,2,3]
b[1]=[2,3,4]
print(b[1])
```